# check if description unique in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have table products, and in this table I have column description. 
How in laravel, when user add product, I can check if title unique? 
My code:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'description' => 'required|unique:products|min:5|max:255',
    ]
}
```

But this rules is not working. People can add styles on text, and laravel not want check text if is unique. How I can check text with added styles on ckeditor?

Comment: how you are calling `rules()` method ?

Comment: this is custom request

Comment: can you show this ?, and also check my answer.

Comment: your answer is not working in my cause.. but my code, this is simple custom request.. in controller: ``public function addProduct(AddProductRequest $request)
    {``

Comment: Please add all code related to validation. The idea is to change `description` field only for validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove tags by [strip_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) method and check only text value from request before validation,

```
$request['description'] = strip_tags($request->description);
```

Check one example of [strip_tags](https://eval.in/978371)